# Jquery Validate form validation with Foundation Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, zurb-foundation

I am building a website that has a form on it with the jQuery Validate plugin.
Required fields got validated by the required tag, the only problem is that when using the Foundation frameworks Accordion module, all the modules got validated.

When submitting the form, all the required fields got validated, but I need only the open accordion tabs to be validated (the required fields), see the example beneath:

The form looks like:

```
[Name]*
[Email]*

Tab 1:
[field 1]
[field2*]

Tab 2:
[field 3]
[field 4*]
```

Example code:

```
$("form").validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.attr("type") == "radio") {
            error.insertBefore(element);
        }
    },
    ignore: ':hidden'
});
```

Example html (stripped):

```
    <form> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-3 columns">
            <label for="right-label" class="text-right">Lastname*</label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
            <input type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="Lastname" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
                <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Option 1</a>
                    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="small-3 columns">
                                <label for="right-label" class="text-right">Field*</label>
                            </div>
                        <div class="small-9 columns">
                            <input type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="Field" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <button type="submit"class="button round orange">Akkoord</button>
</form>
```

jQuery Foundation Accordion: [Accordion example](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion.html)
jQuery Validate: [jQuery Validate documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Comment: You do not need `ignore: ':hidden'`... **by default**, this plugin will ignore all hidden, hidden type, and invisible fields.